# automatically change an html item when something changes in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have this code:

```
$resource=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user='$id'");
$num=mysql_num_rows($resource);

if ($num==0) echo '<li><a style="color:red">messages (0)</a></li>';
else echo '<li><a style="color:blue">messages ('.$num.')</a></li>';
```

It searches into the database and if it finds new messages for the user, it changes the colour of the font, displaying the number of unread messages. the problem is that the page has to be refreshed first and this is not happening automatically.

Unfortunately, auto-refresh is not an option.
Can i use AJAX? would perl do any good?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`setInterval()`](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) or a `setTimeout()` to call regularly an [AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that would make a call to your server

Comment: answering @jmax. i'm familiar with setTimeout. wouldn't that slow down the whole thing? i don't know, i'm just asking

Comment: depending on which frequency you want the refresh but *every* javascript will slow down the computer :). Actually, i'd rather wonder about your server and database load (depending on the number of users you will have)

Comment: to @jmax the frequency is about 1 sec and 3 AJAX functions are executed simulyaneously. i'm starting to think that it's too heavy for the server. i don't have any experience on it so i don't know the limits of these things

Comment: i'd say it depends on your server and the weight of the executed code through the request. You can ask the question on another topic of Stackoverflow because i'm sure some experts will have much to say about this topic